# What does a=z++ mean as a increment in a for loop statement?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I came across a for loop statement in a C++ code, like this:

```
for (i=N, z=head; i>0;  a=z++, i--) {}
```

The type of `z`, `head` and `a` is a pointer to an array. `a=z++` here really confused me. Could anyone give me some guidance on what `a=z++` does in this for loop? And what is the relationship between `z` and `a`?

Comment: Post complete, compilable code.

Comment: I assume you mean that `z`, `head` and `a` are pointers to elements in an array? Unless they are pointers to arrays within an array of arrays?

Comment: You are right. They are pointers to elements in an array. I was wondering when the assign to a and increment of z happen inside the loop.  Do you think I can change this for loop statement to :    z=head; for （i=N; i>0; i--）{ ....original operations...; a=z; z++; }  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to freshen up your C++ grammar.

In any context (loop or no loop) `a = z++` means 'increment the value of `z`, and use the pre-incremented value of `z` to assign it to `a`.

In other words, in world of integers, if `a` is 100 and `z` is 10, after this executes `z` is 11, and `a` is 10.

In case those are pointers within arrays, the same logic applies - if `z` points to tenth element, after this statement `a` points to tenth, and `z` points to eleventh.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So can I change this for statement to this?
 z=head;  for （i=N;  i>0; i--）{ ....original operations...;   a=z;  z++; }

Comment: @HumbeCoder There is practically no difference between `a=z++;` and `a=z; z++;`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux   Thank you for your response. My confusion was kind of about when "a=z; z++;"  will be executed. Since "i++" is executed at the end of the current iteration, I am guessing "a=z; z++;"  should also be executed at the end of the for-loop, am I right?

Comment: @HumbeCoder You should read about [`operator,`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do). A `for` loop as three components : the initialization, the condition and the iteration expression. They are separated by`i=N, z=head` for the initialization, `i>0` for the condition and `a=z++, i--` for the iteration expression. If you were to literally substitute `a=z++` with `a=z; z++` you would be introducing a semicolon which would break up your iteration expression. It would be more accurate to say, in this case, that `a=z++` is equivalent to `a=z, z++`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you so much for your guidance.